# Error when saving variables in Django template context

Tags: python, json, django, django-templates

I've made a webpage that submits a request to an api that returns a JSON object of information about a Concert tour based on the parameters provided by the user in a form. I'm able to successfully get the JSON and parse it. The structure of the data is a set of Concert objects with information about the venue, the date, location, etc. each of which I'm parsing and saving to a list (which is working). I then need to be able to display these as list (formatted as if they were concerts on Stubhub or Ticketmaster) in the template corresponding to the view.

To do this, I thought I could just store each list as a variable in the context dictionary for the template as I had already been doing with literal strings. For some reason, when I try this I'm getting `Exception Value: local variable 'form_artistSelect' referenced before assignment` for the following code:

```
def search(request):
    form = SearchForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form_artistSelect = urllib2.quote(form.cleaned_data.get("artist_select"))
        form_city =   urllib2.quote(form.cleaned_data.get("city"))
        form_state = urllib2.quote(form.cleaned_data.get("state"))
        mile_radius = urllib2.quote(form.cleaned_data.get("radius"))
        #print "testing"
        url = "http://api.bandsintown.com/events/search?artists[]=" + form_artistSelect + "&location=" +form_city+","+ form_state+"&radius="+ mile_radius + "&format=json&app_id=YOUR_APP_ID"
        data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))

        #titles = [ i.get("title") for i in data]
        raw_dts = [str(i.get("datetime")) for i in data]

        #formatted_dts = [i.get("formatted_datetime") for i in data]
        ticket_urls = [str(i.get("ticket_url")) for i in data]
        ticket_statuses = [str(i.get("ticket_status")) for i in data]
        venue_names = [str(i.get("venue").get("name")) for i in data]
        venue_cities = [str(i.get("venue").get("city")) for i in data]
        venue_region = [str(i.get("venue").get("region")) for i in data]
context = {
        "form_artistSelect" : form_artistSelect,
        "raw_dts" : raw_dts,
        "ticket_urls" : ticket_urls,
        "ticket_statuses" : ticket_statuses,
        "venue_names" : venue_names,
        "venue_cities" : venue_cities,
        "venue_region" : venue_region,
        "form" : form
    }
    return render(request,"searchform.html" , context)
```

Why would be causing a problem with this approach? If this isn't the correct way to pass parsed data from a response to a template, then how should I go about doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At what level of indentation is the line `context = {` at?

As posted this is a syntax error. I imagine though that it is indented to the same level as the `if` statement.

`form_artistSelect` is assigned only if `form.is_valid()` is `True` so, if the form is *not* valid, `form_artistSelect` is undefined when you build the `context` dictionary. That will cause the exception that you see.

You need to figure out why the form is invalid, or move all of the code into the `if form.is_valid():` block and add an `else` to render and return an error (or whatever is appropriate for your application).